# Calling an actual API with vertx in Test

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to check the data returned by the call, its suppose to be an array with name "data"

```
"success": true,
  "serverName": "mma.tour.com",
  "data": [
    [
      "01.08.2018",
      [
        "01.08"
      ],
      "Ср",
      8,
      "09.08",
      [....... etc
```

My api call goes like this

```
  public static JsonObject clientTest() {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

        client
            .get("https://www.mma-tour.com/tariffsearch/getResult?" +
                "priceMin=0&priceMax=1500000&currency=533067&nightsMin=6&nightsMax=8" +
                "&hotelClassId=269506&accommodationId=2&rAndBId=15350&tourType=1&" +
                "locale=ru&cityId=786&countryId=1104&after=01.08.2018&before=01.08.2018&" +
                "hotelInStop=false&specialInStop=false&version=2&tourId=1285&" +
                "tourId=12689&tourId=12706&tourId=143330&tourId=9004247&" +
                "tourId=4433&tourId=5736&tourId=139343&tourId=4434&tourId=12691&" +
                "tourId=21301&tourId=12705&tourId=149827&tourId=4151426&hotelClassBetter=true&" +
                "rAndBBetter=true&noTicketsTo=false&noTicketsFrom=false&searchTypeId=3&" +
                "recommendedFlag=false&salePrivateFlag=false&onlineConfirmFlag=false&contentCountryId=1102")
            .send(ar -> {
                if (ar.succeeded()) {
                    // Obtain response
                    HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
                    Tour tour = new Tour.TourBuilder().build();
                    JsonObject myTourJson = response.bodyAsJsonObject();
                    myTourJson.getJsonArray("data"); //here

                } else {
                }
            });
        return null;
    }
```

Above i tried to get data and write a test to check some data is returned but it fails during debug doesnt even get to "data"

Comment: "write a test" - you mean unit test?

Comment: yes a unit test just to see that it returns data from the api but it doesnt return it just fails am i doing something wrong

Comment: You should mock the data for unit tests instead of relying on actual data. Please see mockito framework

Comment: i know about mockito framework i want to the actual data , the purpose of the test is to get actual data

Comment: Like I said unit tests should not rely on real world data, it's against the best practices.

Comment: ok so how can i test that it actually calls real data before i use the method in production

Comment: The web address https://www.mma-tour.com/ isn't available

Comment: i just changed because its on stack ok use this www.tez-tour.com it will work replace mm-tour

Comment: @Rakesh i am waiting for your response